# is it possible to show an ovelay div with loading image inside , during postbacks not callbacks?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, postback, overlay, modal-dialog

is it possible to show an ovelay div with loading image inside , during postbacks not callbacks?

i had an ovelay=OffDiv (modal) div during callbacks and it was working perfectly...

for some reason in one of my page , ajax mode made some problems , so i forced to use postback instead.

now i want to show that Overlay div during postbacks...

plz look at the below code for understanding my meaning:

(but this codes did not prepare my purpose , why?)

```
    protected void radcbImagesGroup_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, Telerik.Web.UI.RadComboBoxSelectedIndexChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "MyScriptOffDivOn", "OffDivOn();" , true);
        Session["SelectedImageGroup_ID"] = e.Value;
        if (e.Value == "0")
        {
            lblTitleOfImages_Loc.Text = "some stuff";
            lblTitleOfImages_LocName.Text = "some stuff";
            RadRotator.Items.Clear();
            RadRotator.DataBind();
        }
        else
        {
            lblTitleOfImages_Loc.Text = "some stuff";
            lblTitleOfImages_LocName.Text = e.Text;
            RadRotator.Items.Clear();
            RadRotator.DataBind();
        }
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "MyScriptOffDivOff", "OffDivOff();" , true);
    }
```

is it possible to this job during postbacks?

thanks for attention

Comment: Once your page posts to the server, execution of the page on the client pretty much stops....

Comment: but how loading progress works before loading a page ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once the page has begun the postback, the client will not receive any data from the server until the server code is complete. Your commands to OffDivOn() and OffDivOff() are not getting sent to the client. Your options are:

1. Use AJAX to submit your form. Check out jQuery's [form serialization](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/)
2. Begin showing your loading image before the submit happens using javascript. Try wiring to the onclick handler of your submit button or handing the onsubmit event of your form and call OffDivOn().